# How to solve the following trig triangle word problem?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, word-problem

A radio antenna that is 40 feet high stands on top of the Wentworth Building. From a point in front of Bailey's Drugstore, the angle of elevation of the top of the pole is 54°54'and the angle of elevation of the bottom of the pole is 47°30'.How tall is the Wentforth Building.

I think the Wentforth Building is 40-X

I have a diagram I don't think I'm right but here 
[image]

Thats how angle of elevation is supposed to be right, like straight and then diagonal? I don't really know what to do after this, How am I supposed to solve this?

*BD is Bailey's Drugstore and WB is Wentworth Building*

Comment: Well, I don't know, but I'd assume that the angle of elevation to the base of the tower was a sub-angle of the angle of elevation to the top.  That is to say, sighting at $47^\circ\,30'$ spots the base and sighting at $54^\circ\,54'$ spots the top.  Assuming this is correct, let $X$ be the height of WB, so $X+40$ is the height of WB+tower, let $Y$ be the distance to WB and compute the two tangents.

Comment: [Here's a better diagram.](https://i.imgur.com/dGZXU4T.jpg) The two angles of elevation overlap.

Comment: but aren't we just finding the height of WB isn't that X-40 or are we counting the tower as well, so you're saying 54°54′ would be like near the radio tower?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Oh I don't really get it can you explain? so is the height of the tower 40-x or is it 40+x?

Comment: Using @lulu's variables, $X$ is the height of the tower (not including the antenna). $X+40$ is the height of the tower including the antenna. $54^\circ54'$ is the angle of elevation to the top of the antenna.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger There's two angles, which one will I use to find X?

Comment: Both. Call the distance between the buildings (the length of the horizontal line on the bottom) $Y$. Using the definition of tangent (opposite over adjacent), what's the tangent of $54^\circ54'$? What's the tangent of $47^\circ30'$?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger so $$Tan(54°54′)=40+x/y$$ but there's two unknowns right?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger How would I solve this?

Comment: What's the tangent of the other angle?

Comment: the same I think $$Tan(47°30')=x+40/y $$

Comment: Should I equal them like find x in one and then plug that value in the other?

Answer (score 2):

Adapting the earlier diagram, consider the triangle ABC.

We know that $AB=40$, that $\angle ACB=7^{\circ}24'$ (difference between two given angles) and that $\angle CAB=35^{\circ}06'$.

Use the Sine Rule to find $BC$.

Then the height of the building is the angle opposite a $47^{\circ}30'$ angle in a right-angled triangle with hypotenuse $BC$. Just use straightforward trigonometry for that.

[image]